# Resource for c# codegen best practices

Tags: c#, code-generation

I am looking for one or more resources on best practices for c# codegen (writing c# via code at runtime).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually wrote [an article](http://blog.pnbconsulting.com.au/?p=120) on this a while back.

Comment: Link rot! Can you update this and copy a précis into the answer?